# How can names be arranged in alphabetic order from top to bottom preseding to the first character

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have some names arrange alphabatically, designed as

```
A
 abc

B
 bcd
```

they are in three columns, problem is some names are not placed in under the letter..

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xabf/)

Under H there are no names so it is written as No sellers, but it was not under the H .. 
I have used the column css.. Please help me to fix the css .

**EDIT**

For best view please use mozilla firefox web browser

Sometimes it looks like

```
A       cde            good
  abc   E              H
B        edffffff       hair
  Bcd   F
C        fail
        G
```

here cde should be present under letter C but it is showing in the second column..

Also same for G the string good should be present under G but it is placing in 3rd column.

Comment: I don't see your issue. Everything appears to be aligned as your example above.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want. The 'No sellers' under 'H' is the same as any other.

Comment: I want the No Sellers or any names present for H should be align under it .. Now No Sellers is placing at the second column.

Comment: So it is for every name AND no sellers that are incorrect?

Comment: yes.. the design should be like that .. as there are are no names under H I have added a default option as No Sellers...

Comment: I really can't understand the problem here. What is wrong with the letter H?

Comment: How do you want a "No Sellers" row look like?

Comment: @Aioros: please see the editted content of the question.

Comment: @Debadatt Is the problem that you have orphaned entries when using the column layout (i.e. entries that are moved to the next column rather than remaining in their group)?

Comment: Looks like a definition list marked up with unordered lists and divs.

Answer (score 1):

HTML has some odd rules to flatten / reduce white space in some places. In your case, the left margin is ignored when a new column begins. The same would happen if you had a top margin.

I think the only solution is to indent elements by using `<span style="width:2em" />` inside of the `div`.

Alternatively, you can try using nested lists instead of using `div`.

That said, it still looks ugly when the items for "H" are in a different column than the "H" itself. I suggest to layout the page in several columns manually on the server and then render a three-column table so you can get:

```
   ...      H (contd.)
   ...         h2
   ...
   ...
   ...
   H
      h1
```